# No SLF4J providers were found

Tags: java, logging, slf4j

Have two dependencies added to my project
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWnME.png) via Maven.

However, I see that org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:2.0.6 is not added (at least from IntelliJ log I understand so).

IntelliJ console output:

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.0.5.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=56496:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
-classpath /Users/arturaspaluskinas/Documents/JavaRushTasks/out/production/4.JavaCollections:/Users/arturaspaluskinas/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.13.1/junit-4.13.1.jar:/Users/arturaspaluskinas/.m2/repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:/Users/arturaspaluskinas/.m2/repository/org/junit/jupiter/junit-jupiter/5.8.1/junit-jupiter-5.8.1.jar:/Users/arturaspaluskinas/.m2/repository/org/junit/jupiter/junit-jupiter-api/5.8.1/junit-jupiter-api-5.8.1.jar:/Users/arturaspaluskinas/.m2/repository/org/opentest4j/opentest4j/1.2.0/opentest4j-1.2.0.jar:/Users/arturaspaluskinas/.m2/repository/org/junit/platform/junit-platform-commons/1.8.1/junit-platform-commons-1.8.1.jar:/Users/arturaspaluskinas/.m2/repository/org/apiguardian/apiguardian-api/1.1.2/apiguardian-api-1.1.2.jar:/Users/arturaspaluskinas/.m2/repository/org/junit/jupiter/junit-jupiter-params/5.8.1/junit-jupiter-params-5.8.1.jar:/Users/arturaspaluskinas/.m2/repository/org/junit/jupiter/junit-jupiter-engine/5.8.1/junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.1.jar:/Users/arturaspaluskinas/.m2/repository/org/junit/platform/junit-platform-engine/1.8.1/junit-platform-engine-1.8.1.jar:/Users/arturaspaluskinas/.m2/repository/javax/xml/bind/jaxb-api/2.3.1/jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar:/Users/arturaspaluskinas/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/2.0.6/slf4j-api-2.0.6.jar com.javarush.task.MyLogger

SLF4J: No SLF4J providers were found.
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.

documentation https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html says that adding one of slf4j-nop.jar slf4j-simple.jar, slf4j-reload4j.jar, slf4j-jdk14.jar or logback-classic.jar on the class path should solve the problem.

Any ideas why Java or IDEA cannot find slf4j ?

Comment: Can you show the dependencies in your pom itself? Because maybe the scope of `slf4j-simple` is set to `test`, which means it will only be available for unit tests.

Comment: Please attach pom.xml to your post

Answer (score 0):

use the below dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.6</version>
</dependency>
```

and keep the log4j.properties file in **src/main/resources**.

a sample file for printing the log in the console.:

```
log4j.rootLogger=debug,console

log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %L - %m%n
```